# Grails save(flush:true) not immediately persisting to database

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using following code -

```
Topic topic = new Topic()
topic.name = "y u no save"
topic.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)

def promiseList = new PromiseList()
subtopicNames.each { sName ->
  promiseList << Topic.async.task {
       Subtopic subtopic = new Subtopic()
       subtopic.name = sName
       /* ... long running tasks like web service call ... */
       log.info("Topic Id : $topic.id")
       subtopic.topic = topic
       subtopic.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
  }
}

def subtopics = promiseList.get()
```

I get this error-

```
Detail: Key (topic_id)=(517333) is not present in table "topic".; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "subtopic" violates foreign key constraint "fkfd7d3e7098cf2d58"
  Detail: Key (topic_id)=(517333) is not present in table "topic".
```

When I check database for topic with id 517333, it actually doesn't exist, while the log in `aync.task` block prints 'Topic Id : 517333'. What is going on here, how to force the topic save when required.

```
Topic - 

class Topic {
  String name
  static hasMany = [subtopics: Subtopic]
}

Subtopic - 

class Subtopic {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [topic: Topic]
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to add your subtopics asynchronously ? Async would probably be useful if you were doing expensive and long-running processes, but I'm not sure it will help gaining any performance for simple database inserts with no other processing going on... Also, where do you put this code ? Is it in a service method with the default transactions on ?

Comment: The code posted above is stripped down version. There are actually long running tasks happening, like calling web services etc in the subtopic creation.
Yes code is in a service with default transactions on.

Comment: Ok, can you paste your Topic and Subtopic domain classes as well ?

Comment: Added. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The way to add domain instances into a collection that uses a hasMany relationship is to add the child domain to the parent class' collection.
Try this :

```
def promiseList = new PromiseList()
def topic = new Topic(name: 'main topic')
topic.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
def subtopics = ['subtopic 1', 'subtopic 2']

subtopics.each { topicName ->
    promiseList << Topic.async.task {
        Subtopic subtopic = new Subtopic(name: topicName)
        // adding to the topic will cascade saves of the subtopics by default.
        topic.addToSubtopics(subtopic)
        /* ... long running tasks like web service call ... */
        return subtopic
    }
}

// wait for tasks to complete
def subtopicList = promiseList.get()

// Saving the topic will cascade saves of the child subtopics
topic.save(failOnError: true, flush:true)
```

If you want to still do it your way, you may disable the constraint on subtopic's topic property to allow for null :

```
class Subtopic {
    //...
    static constraints = {
        topic nullable: true
    }
}
```

Then you can do :

```
Subtopic subtopic = new Subtopic(name : topicName)
subtopic.save(flush:true)
```

And, after the promises are synchronized :

```
def subtopicList = promiseList.get()
subtopicList.each {
    topic.addToSubtopics(it)
}
topic.save(failOnError: true, flush:true)
```

Comment: I was using a similar solution before. The problem with this is that, since I am using promises which have different hibernate session, I have to merge the subtopic instance back in the hibernate session of main thread before calling save on topic. This is good for top level properties in subtopic class, but my subtopic also has associated objects which are not merged by merge method

Comment: Then I guess you need to disable the constraint on subtopic's topic property to allow for a nullable property. See my code edit in a minute...